# BIRT - how do I force a column to output values in "Decimal"?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, casting, type-conversion, birt

I can do that easily on an existing report by double-clicking a column that has no customized expression for it (i.e. dataSetRow["NAME_OF_COLUMN"]) but when I run into a column with a customized expression, I have no access to its data type, as double-clicking on it only opens the "Expression Builder" window.

Is there a way to somehow "cast" the result of the customized expression, or perhaps feed it into a function that does the conversion? I looked around the various options and settings, but found nothing related to my case.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the custom format for data, it is very helpful when you write Javascript which will format the column data dynamically.

There are other predefined methods are available which can be used to check if the value does not contains any decimal then you can add .00 to make decimal justified value.

```
If(!dataSetRow["NAME_OF_COLUMN"]).contains(".")) {
   var xcustomeformat = dataSetRow["NAME_OF_COLUMN"]) + ".00";
}
```

Similary, if any value comes like 101.4 and you want out put as 101.40 then you can check the length of characters after decimal character and add additional ZEROs as needed.